# Why do I get the message unexpected argument

Tags: python, class, methods, syntax, pycharm

The message refers to the line
`if self.find_action(self, bit) is not None:`

If I run I get the error:
TypeError: find_action() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```
def find_action(self, search_term):
    for action in self.actions:
        bits = re.split(";", action)
        for bit in bits:
            if bit == search_term:
                return action
    return None

def check_action_free(self, params):
    bits = re.split(";", params)
    for bit in bits:
        if self.find_action(self, bit) is not None:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: The call to "find_action" should not pass "self" as an argument (I'm assuming these are both methods in some class).

Comment: And [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self#:~:text=Python%20decided%20to%20do%20methods%20in%20a%20way%20that%20makes%20the%20instance%20to%20which%20the%20method%20belongs%20be%20passed%20automatically).

Comment: Thanks to both. That was the answer, although I am still digesting the explanation that Zigarek sent.